# How to find the person with the highest grade

Tags: query-optimization

In my PieCloudDB database, I have a user table and a grade table, where the grade table records the users' grade information. (Example data).

users:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Buck |
| 2 | Mercy |
| 3 | Nika |
| 4 | Camille |
| 5 | Daisy |

grade_info:

| user_id | grade_num | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | add |
| 2 | 4 | add |
| 1 | 1 | reduce |
| 3 | 2 | add |
| 4 | 2 | add |
| 5 | 3 | add |
| 3 | 1 | reduce |
| 4 | 2 | add |

For example, the first row indicates that the user with user_id 1 has gained 5, and the third row indicates that the same user has then lost 1.

I want to find the id, name, and total grade of the user with the highest grade using an SQL query. There may be multiple users with the same grade. The query results should be sorted in ascending order by id. The result of the above example is as follows:

| id | name | total_grade |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Buck | 4 |
| 2 | Mercy | 4 |
| 4 | Camille | 4 |

I have tried the following, but I feel that my approach is too complex. Is there a simpler query?

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, g.total_grade
FROM users u
JOIN (
    SELECT user_id, SUM(
        CASE WHEN type = 'add' THEN grade_num
             WHEN type = 'reduce' THEN -grade_num
             ELSE 0
        END
    ) AS total_grade
    FROM grade_info
    GROUP BY user_id
) g ON u.id = g.user_id
WHERE g.total_grade = (
    SELECT MAX(total_grade)
    FROM (
        SELECT user_id, SUM(
            CASE WHEN type = 'add' THEN grade_num
                 WHEN type = 'reduce' THEN -grade_num
                 ELSE 0
            END
        ) AS total_grade
        FROM grade_info
        GROUP BY user_id
    ) max_grades
)
ORDER BY u.id;
```

Comment: Please tag the RDBMS you are using

Comment: You would remove unneeded complexity by just storing positive or negative values, presumably there are only ever two types.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't find the RDBMS I'm using in tag list, and I don't have enough reputation to add a new tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CTE (Common Table Expression) syntax for the query in your PieCloudDB database. This might help you:

```
with tg AS
    (select
     u.id, u.name, sum(case when gi.type='add' then gi.grade_num else -gi.grade_num end) total_grade
    from users u , grade_info gi
    where u.id = gi.user_id
    group by 1,2
    )
select * from tg
where total_grade = (select max(total_grade) from tg)
order by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

This method has faster execution speed(test in PostgreSQL), but the disadvantage is that it takes up more memory. If you don't mind, you can give it a try in your PieCloudDB Database.

```
select t1.id,t1.name,t0.grade as grade_sum
from(
    select user_id,grade,rank()over(order by grade desc) as t
    from(
        select user_id,sum(case when type='add' then grade_num else -1*grade_num end) as grade
        from grade_info
        group by user_id
        ) a0
) t0
join users as t1
on t0.user_id = t1.id
where t=1
```